# Use regex with express-jsonschema to validate content of array

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I'm using express-jsonschema to validate the schema of a JSON HTTP Post request. This is the schema:

```
var massiveReportSchema = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        email: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        author: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        userId: {
            type: 'array',
            required: true,
            items: {type: 'string'}
        }
    }
}
```

I want to validate that each element in `userId` has the format `"userId account"`. I think I can use regex, but I don't know how. This is the body of an example request:

```
{
    "email": "test.doe@mail.com",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "userId" : [    "100 500", 
                    "101 default", 
                    "102 600"]

}
```

Comment: each item in `userId` must match this regex: `\w+\s\w+` ; is there any conditions except Space character between userId and account in string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple

```
var massiveReportSchema = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        email: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        author: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        userId: {
            type: 'array',
            required: true,
            items: {type: 'string',  pattern: "\d+\s\d+"}
        }
    }
}
```

More information:

https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can validate each element in `userId` using the following way ...

```js
var res = {
    "email": "test.doe@mail.com",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "userId" : [
      "100 500",
      "101 default",
      "105900",
      "102 600"
    ]
};
res.userId.forEach(function(e) {
  var result = 'Validating "' + e + '" | Status : ' + /\w+\s\w+/.test(e);
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: thank you! is there any way to do it using express-jsonschema  directly?

Comment: @JuanDavid maybe yes, not sure. never used express-jsonschema.

Comment: It's possible. See answer below. Thanks for your help.